# set string value to object key - value

Tags: java, json

Set the value in a value key object

value string Object:

```
"{\"List\":\"
[[\\\"000000001\\\",12,0,0,3518,3520,11180,10000,3520,-4.68,-173,3537,0,-156,0,0,\\\"0\\\",3669,3510,3669,2948113,\\\"\\\\/Date(1533715176000)\\\\/\\\",3693,\\\"N1\\\",8,\\\"13\\\",\\\"NAME\\\",3509,3877],
[\\\"000000002\\\",13,0,0,970000,1010000,10000,9990,1000000,0,-1,1000000,0,-1,2759,1,\\\"2759000000\\\",1000000,1000000,1000000,1,\\\"\\\\/Date(1533714918000)\\\\/\\\",1000001,\\\"N4\\\",8,\\\"45\\\",\\\"NAME\\\",950001,1050001], ...
```

set to this class:

```
Number.Class
private String id;
private String wordNumber
, ....
```

An example to convert fields:

```
setId = 000000001  - setId = 000000002

setWordNumber = 12 - setwordNumber = 13
```

I did this:

```
String json = " "{\"List\":\"
[[\\\"000000001\\\",12,0,0,3518,3520,11180,10000,3520,-4.68,-173,3537,0,-156,0,0,\\\"0\\\",3669,3510,3669,2948113,\\\"\\\\/Date(1533715176000)\\\\/\\\",3693,\\\"N1\\\",8,\\\"13\\\",\\\"NAME\\\",3509,3877],";
    Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){});
```

But unfortunately it was not :(

Someone can guide me,
Please

Comment: You are supposed to write a question about your code, not request others to write your code for you. Please update your question.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want to parse the JSON to a Java object?

There's various libraries which can do this, like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for example.

With Gson, you could do:

```
YourClass object = new Gson().fromJson(json, YourClass.class);
```

If that's not what you're trying to achieve, please clarify the question.